# How to sum a value of rows when searching for specific text

Tags: arrays, excel, function

Please see the screenshot, but it's like this:

```
Column A    Column B
User 1      20
User 2      30
User 3      20
User 4      10
User 1      40
User 3      40
User 1      10
User 4      20
User 2      30
User 1      20
User 4      50
User 4      20
User 2      10
```

This is a simple list, and the actual list is spread across 27 worksheets. But I would like the equation to be on each worksheet.

How do I search Column A for a value of "1" and SUM up the values for Column B. SO I should have a result of 90 for User 1, 70 for User 2, 60 for User 3 and 100 for User 4.

Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: look into [sumif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)

Comment: But will this allow me to search with an "*" in the field? SO I can look for "1".  i tried this earlier, and it just wouldn't work for me :-(

Comment: `=SUMIF(A:A,"*1*",B:B)`

Comment: That did the trick, I was adding in a load of other characters like ' and =, so darn simple! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be for cell C2 (just drag downwards):

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B)
```

[MS Office Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)

**edit:** Had a little mistake there, sorry. Now it should work.

Comment: THanks for that. Had a response from Simco as well. Just got it working, thank you!